# Turn form builder response into HTML

Tags: 8, forms

I have a node type called "competition". I can get a form for it like so:

```
$values = array('type' => 'competition');
$node = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('node')
  ->create($values);

$form = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getFormObject('node', 'default')
  ->setEntity($node);
$form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm($form);
```

In a controller it's easy enough to return $form and it will be rendered. But I want to do other things with this form so I need it back as HTML. How can I turn $form into fully rendered html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to use:

```
$html = drupal_render($form);
```

Just like you would do in Drupal 7. Not great, but solves my problem.

Comment: Why not let it render normally?

Comment: I want to place different node creation forms in different tabs in my custom html. I could probably use "field groups" but I ran into a wall with a few issues. SO hacking them all into my own custom html code is just a lot easier.

Comment: Just put the form variables to your Twig templates. They will be rendered automatically.